# How to create a Facebook Like or Fan page?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I successfully integrated a FaceBook application into my project (the regular FaceBook page where you post something on your wall):

[image]

But I was wondering if someone can help me out how to get a facebook fan page or like page on this? I dont wan't publish story "Post To Your Wall" and entering message, I just want user to get that fan page a 'Like' button and gets status updates (no post to fan page yet).

Hope someone can help me out, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get the RSS feed of the fan page and parse that I believe.

Comment: sorry to ask, where can I get the RSS feed?